# How do I fix error with if statement in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create my first .bat game type thing. Im trying to create a guess the number.

```
@echo off
:start
cls
set /p num=Guess the Number! 1-10

if %num%==5 (
echo Correct
pause
)

if %num% GTR 5 (
echo Hmmm... Think Lower.
pause
)
goto start


if %num% LSS 5 (
echo Hmmm... Think Higher.
pause
)
goto start
```

No error messages where shown.

Comment: What *error* are you trying to fix? What problem are you having with the code you posted? You've not indicated any specific problem or asked any specific question. Before we can help, you need to clearly explain the problem you're having and ask an actual question related to the code you've posted. Use the [edit] link to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you wrote. The problem is that your `goto start` are not inside the parenthesis, so when it reaches that line, it clears the screen and starts again. I would update your code like this:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
set /p num=Guess the Number! 1-10 

if %num%==5 (
echo Correct
pause
exit /b
)

if %num% GTR 5 (
echo Hmmm... Think Lower.
)

if %num% LSS 5 (
echo Hmmm... Think Higher.
)
goto start
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for helping with this. I will take into consideration all these helpful answers.